# Python Django: change font color for part of string found in another list

Tags: python, django

Here are the lists in views.py:

```
my_list1 = ['I like the hotel.','I like the red car and the tree.']
my_list2 = ['hotel','tree','red car']
```

Here is what I'm trying to do on index.html:

```
I like the <font color="red">hotel</font>.
I like the <font color="red">red car</font> and the <font color="red">tree</font>.
```

On index.html, I have the following to make the entire item in red. But, I  cannot change font color for the items found in my_list2 only. Please help!

```
<table>
        {% for item in my_list1 %}
        <tr>
          <td id="red">{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: this is not a tuple `['I like the hotel.','I like the red car and the tree.']`, it's a list

Comment: sorry they are lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) and call it for each item inside the loop `my_list1`

[Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is a powerful way to do it:

```
from django import template
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def add_font(obj,my_list2):
    output = obj
    for item in my_list2:
        output = re.sub(item,"<font color='red'>{}</font>".format(item),output)
        # be careful not to add white space around the {} like this "<font color='red'> {} </font>"
    return output
```

In your template , you can loop with the tag

> I suppose that you already the two list to your template

`file_name` represents the name of the file containing your custom tag function, you have to load it before using it in your template.

```
{% load file_name %}

<table>
{% for item in my_list1 %}
    <tr>
      <td id="red">{{item|add_font:my_list2}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```